# Moving Value of a pointer to a value in C++ inline assembly (window)

Tags: c++, pointers, assembly

Here is the situation:

I have the

```
char c1 = 'a'
```

and

```
char c2* = somePointer
```

Now I want to move the Value that **c2** points at into the char **c1** using **assembly**.

```
mov c1, c2
```

does not work.

Thanks in advance

Edit: The idea behind this is that assembly can access parts of the memory C++ can't reach. So I want assembly to copy some data from outside into a spot in my accessible memory section.

Comment: note that I am using Windows, like I _meant_ to say in the title

Comment: `mov eax, c2`, `mov al, byte ptr [eax]`, `mov c1, al`

Comment: @Zain You can edit your question after you asked it.

Answer (score 1):

`c2` contains an address to the first byte of target character(s) memory. `c1` contains a character value.

To dereference, use **[ ]**.

```
mov c1,BYTE PTR [c2]
```

Comment: @Zain: In case you want to look how an assembly looks like you can also take a look at godbolt: http://goo.gl/g6APkW In this case with -O0

Comment: You can't move memory to memory in x86 assembly. You'll have to use a register as an intermediate.

Comment: Right, memory->memory doesn't work, my code was just an example. His byte can be stored f.e. in `al` as intermediate.